# the name appstate isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I  am getting the error the name appstate isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument in my flutter code

code:
https://github.com/1-creator/auth

error:

```
Widget mutationComponent(context) {

final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context);
```

...

what i tried

-creating class 'AppState'

-flutter clean

-invalidating cache

Comment: What is `c` in `AppState extends c`?

Comment: corrected that  it was a typo error

Answer (score 1):

seems i had not imported app_state.dart from the lib package state

```
  import 'package:know/state/app_state.dart';
```

just added the import and the problem was solved